# python script problem

Tags: python, biopython

I am trying to run a python script, the error that appear is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/erange/geneMrnaCountsWeighted.py", line 266, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/erange/geneMrnaCountsWeighted.py", line 51, in main
    options.extendGenome, options.replaceModels)
  File "/opt/erange/geneMrnaCountsWeighted.py", line 250, in geneMrnaCountsWeighted
    tagCount += tagValue / tagDenom
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tagValue' referenced before assignment
```

Anyone could help me?

Comment: local variable 'tagValue' referenced before assignment. Where did you define tagValue? See, you didn't. Give us some code for more clues.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with biopython.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an old version of that particular script. Compare the old version with the newest version:

http://woldlab.caltech.edu/gitweb/?p=erange.git;a=blob;f=geneMrnaCountsWeighted.py;hb=5e4ae21098dba3d1edcf11e7279da0d84c3422e4

http://woldlab.caltech.edu/gitweb/?p=erange.git;a=blob;f=geneMrnaCountsWeighted.py;h=74e7a0cd817e699af6b398960578f576a030f7e4;hb=HEAD

Comment: @Niklas: Thanks! The name of the script sounded related to my field, so I thought I'd look it up.. Hope it helps the lalorto in solving his problem.

Answer (score 2):

This error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tagValue' referenced before assignment

Says that the variable `tagValue` was used before it was assigned a value, like this:

```
a = 2
b = 4

print b + c
```

In this case, `c` was referenced before it was assigned, so Python has no idea what to do with that variable.U

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the line...
`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tagValue' referenced before assignment`
Need to explain anything?

Comment: Maybe the line above, where the exact location and even a printed line of the failing code is provided.